# How does DatagramSocket receive packet everytime and does not stuck

Tags: java, sockets, udp

I create a DatagramSocket.
When I am waiting for the packet, I cannot do anything until the packet is received.
If I want to do something, such as print something when I am waiting for the packet.
How do I do it?

This is my code.

```
private DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(8080);
private DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket();
bool b = true;
int x = 0;

do {
  socket.receive(packet);
  //if I receive a packet, print the payload of the packet
  System.out.println(x);
  x++;
} while (b);
```

I want to keep print the "x". If I receive a packet, I will print the payload of the packet.

or

Can I put the receive function on the background? When I receive a packet, I print it immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this case, you can use threads. You are giving your main thread to infinite loop so that you can't do anything outside of the loop. If you create one more thread and use it for receiving packets, then your main thread can do other works.

Comment: I never teach threads. What class should I use? Can u provide an example?

Comment: Threads will give you functionality of multi tasking. In order to use threads, you need to write on your class "extends Thread" and override the run() method. Write the desired jobs on there and create a thread in main and call the run method. While your created thread receiving packets, your main thread can complete other tasks. There are many examples on the internet, I may suggest this article will help you a lot about the threads.  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_multithreading.htm